# Efficiently iterating large amounts of data

Tags: c++, loops, data-structures, iterator, processing-efficiency

## Introduction

First of, I must say this is being done for an online game server, which keeps track of every object in a map, be it a player or an AI (NPC or however you want to call it).

It must not only keep track of them, but notify among the players their near players. I've solved this, and I'm currently using a multi-threaded approach, which perfectly works.

## My problem

I'm storing all that objects in an hash table. We could consider that hash table to be an `unordered_map`, though I'm in fact using the `rde::hash_map`, as it is faster on inserting and fetching (self tested), though takes more RAM (not an issue now).

The thing is, that map stores a unique ID for the object (64 bits), plus the object pointer, something like:
`rde::hash_map<UInt64, Object*>`

My problem is:

My application (a server) must run in a loop (inside a thread) which must be called every ~50ms, as to keep things runing smooth. The loop code looks as follows:

```
void loop()
{
    UInt32 prev = clock();
    UInt32 prevSleep = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        UInt32 diff = clock() - prev;
        prev = clock();

        maps.update() // Suppose map is a class, which stores the objects map

        if (diff <= 50 + prevSleep)
        {
            prevSleep = 50 + prevSleep - diff;
            sleep(prevSleep);
        }
        else
            prevSleep = 0;
    }
}
```

And now, to the point, the function `map::update()` which is the one causing the loop increasing to values of 4500ms.

Each time an update is called, the map object must check for new object being added to the store, if an object is added, that object must notify all the other objects of it being added, which I do by (pseudocode):

```
foreach obectsToBeAdded as joiner:
    foreach objectsList as object:
        joiner->notify(object);
        object->notify(joiner);
```

Later on, an internal update of each object must be called, I do it by (pseudocode again):

```
foreach objectsList as object:
    object->update();
```

And, if that was not enough, the above loop must be expanded to:

```
foreach objectsList as object:
    object->update()
    
    // Visit all the other objects
    // Called once every 1 sec for the object, not on every call
    foreach objectsList as other:
        if other != object:
            object->visit(other)
```

## **My attemp to optimize this**

Merge the first loop (adding and notifying) with the update loop, as it follows:

```
foreach objectsList as object:
    foreach objectsToBeAdded as joiner:
        object->notify(joiner)
        joiner->notify(object)

    object->update()

    // Called once every 1 sec for the object, not on every call
    foreach objectsList as other:
        if other != object
            object->visit(other)
```

This works while the objects count is not big, as soon as it increases the loops start to take up to 4 seconds, which goes far beyond to the 50ms I'm looking for.

## My question

Is there any other way of optimizing this even more? I've though about using octrees to keep track of the objects positions in the map, but then came to the conclusion that it would only worsen the problem.

I've also divided each map to 35 units (35 is the "view range", LOS) of an entity, so that a given `rde::hash_map` only contains units which are to be seen by each other, thus that need updates. Works as long as objects count is low...

What else could I do? Thank you!

### Note

All those `foreach` are loops using iterators, like `rde::hash_map<...>::iterator` from `objects.begin()` to `objects.end()`

Other optimitzations, such as not updating if there's is no player (a real user, and not a NPC), freeing memory when no player is on a given map, and such, are already being taken into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first optimization that comes to mind besides spatial segmentation so objects are only informed about changes near them (such as with a quadtree) is: Does EVERY object have to be informed about EVERY change? Why not tell each object, 'Every frame, I'll run your `update` method. In your `update` method you can look for everything you want to (for example, there might be a buffer of all changes that occurred this frame/in recent frames) and update yourself as you please'. This way you don't spend CPU cycles notifying objects about things they don't actually need to know or care about.

Also, have you run a CPU profiler on your program, and verified that the hot spots (where the most CPU time is being spent) are where you think they are?

See comments for further discussion:

```
 |
 |
\|/
 V
```

Comment: It is at the moment using some of your suggestions. Each ```rde::hash_map``` collection only contains objects which are by sight range of each other (near them), so they don't get notified of unnecessary objects.

```Object::update()``` method does only (at the moment) evaluate the object position and move it accordingly to the diff time.
```Object::visit(who)``` method simply tells the Object that ```who``` is near, does nothing at all inside.

The time is being spent on the first O(n*m) loop on the joining (n = objects, m = toBeAdded) notification, and on the further O(n^2) visit loop.

Comment: I've profiled it yes.. and those are the results. As a side note, I've also tried unifying both O(n*m) and O(n^2) loops to one, an use extern classes to keep track of the "update status" between two objects, as suggested on: [link](http://www.gamasutra.com/resource_guide/20020916/lambright_01.htm), thus making it a single O(n^2) loop which either notifies a join event or calls the visit method.

Comment: I've also read about cache hit/miss and studied about it, though I see no way of reducing misses while using an hash map. Using an hash map is mandatory due to its fast insert/find and thread-safe iterators (meaning, erasing an object in one thread won't invalidate all the other iterators).

Comment: @ProStage Let me give an example of what I mean - in a shmup with thousands of bullets such as in Touhou, you don't need to inform every bullet of every other bullet's existence. The bare minimum possible is done to ensure correctness of the game (each bullet is advanced, if the bullet specifically cares about the state of other bullets it will explicitly handle that itself when updated, then some fast collision detection algorithm is done, perhaps taking advantage of the fact that only bullets very close to the player matter, bullet sizes are static for the duration of the bullet, etc)

Comment: @ProStage In otherwords, if you're doing huge O(n*m), O(n^2) etc loops of every possible interaction, does every possible interaction need to be specified? Could you do efficient spatial partitioning for the things that actually do need to have it (such as collision detection between physical objects, which can reduce to O(n) instead of O(n^2) if efficient enough) and otherwise objects will only bother to seek out other objects if they know they need to, and ideally they'll have only some things in mind anyway?

Comment: @ProStage (If I am COMPLETELY off base on all of these suggestions, let me know I'm being dumb. I might need to know more about what exactly are the interactions in your program between actors that need simulating.)

Comment: Mmm noo not at all, I do get your point and I might have come up with a solution. I may do a map (rde) for newly added objects only, and, as players are the only to be notified, the player update method (overwritten from the parent class) may ask for that list. That would somewhat reduce the cost. StackOverflow doesn't want me to tag your name with @ =(

Comment: @ProStage You don't have to tag my name because I am the owner of this post, I am automatically notified of any comments on it. And yeah, you're getting the idea - only notify actors that need to be notified, only of changes that they will care about. Also, when sending packets across the network containing changes, send only the changes, not the entire data (think about a game like Minecraft, if it had to send the whole world every update it would take forever, it sends changes only when the changes happen, sends as little as possible and doesn't send things the player cannot see yet)

Comment: Sure, I'm only sending the necessary data, in this case "an entity comes to vision (spawn it)", which definately must be sent.
I've already done some changes and I can see some improvement, I'll go to sleep now, tomorrow I'll finish it and report back, thank you!

Comment: @ProStage If you run into HUGE problems with server side lag, or bandwidth, or jitter, or whatever, don't forget you can take a Realm of the Mad God style approach - if you've ever played it, basically, the client side program simulates what all of the monsters, other players, etc are doing based on the most recent update from the server, and those bullets and monsters are what you fight and dodge. Whenever the server gives you an update then the mobs on screen 'are yanked' towards the real positions and simulation continues. This is easier for hackers, but gives a better experience than lag.

Comment: Sure, I've already though about that, but I've myself hacked (debugging and so), and I know what can be done, so it's not an approach I'd like to take.

Comment: That made it, after some improvements and relaying on the update methods to request everything they need, instead of forcing it from the loop, made the trick.
Thank you.

Comment: @ProStage Awesome to hear!